# DrawerLayout on Fragment hides ListView

Tags: android

I made one activity which contains a ListView and a Fragment (with a DrawerLayout).

Activity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ddffff"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name=".Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview doesn't appear. I think the listview is hidden because of the fragment. I don't know why.

Comment: Both the listview and fragment are displayed full screen. The fragment is on top, so it covers the listview. How do you want the listview and fragment to be positioned on the screen?

Comment: I want the listview to be behind the drawerlayout. Like this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/nav_drawer_final.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the layout for a DrawerLayout, your top element in the layout must be of type DrawerLayout. Try it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is only natural that the fragment covers the entire view, because you set its property as

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This means that the fragment will always "match the parent" meaning will always cover the entire resolution of the parent layout (in this case, the RelativeLayout), you can change it to a numerical value to stop it from doing so, for example if i want my fragment to always have a height of 30dp i would do:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

Alternatively you can just set a secondary layout with a set size and have the fragment fill that instead.

Comment: It returns an error: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Comment: If you're using DrawerLayout, you should follow what Francesc said and create a DrawerLayout that wraps everything, and then create a frameLayout that contains the fragment, followed by the listview itself.